# On the convergence of $\int_0^1 f(x)/(1-x)^a dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ be a continuous positive non-increasing function such that $f(1)=0$ and

$$\int_0^1 f(x)/(1-x)^a dx$$ exists for all $0\leq a \leq 1$ but does not exist for any $a>1$. Does that inform us on the (worst/best) rate of convergence of $f$ to $0$? Or maybe on the convexity/concavity of the function $f$?

I feel like there should exists a $t\in [0,1)$ such that the graph of $f$ after that point $t$ should always be above (or equal to) the graph of $1-x$ to satisfy the convergence property above, and since $f$ is non-increasing, that would make $f$ concave. Is my intuition correct?  How to prove such statement?

Comment: It does not really matter what happens to $f(x)$ for $0 \le x \le 1-\delta$ so  there is 
not much you can say about convexity or concavity across the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: $f(x)=k(1-x)$ would give you convergence of the integral for $a<2$ as it would be $\frac{k}{2-a}$